# Cannot upgrade Debian Jessie to Stable because of deb.sury PHP PPA

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, package-management

I'm attempting to upgrade my Linode Jessie instance to Stable by following [this tutorial](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/upgrading/upgrade-debian-to-the-newest-release/).  I've upgraded my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, and am up to the `$ sudo apt update` step.  When I enter that command, I get the following:

```
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com stable InRelease
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com stable-updates InRelease                         
Ign http://nyc2.mirrors.digitalocean.com stable InRelease                      
Hit http://archive.debian.org jessie-backports InRelease                       
Ign http://nyc2.mirrors.digitalocean.com stable Release.gpg                    
Ign http://nyc2.mirrors.digitalocean.com stable Release                        
Get:1 http://security.debian.org stable/updates InRelease [39.1 kB]            
Get:2 https://packages.sury.org stable InRelease                        
Ign https://packages.sury.org stable InRelease                                 
Get:3 http://mirrors.linode.com stable/main Sources [7,827 kB]                 
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:                 
648ACFD622F3D138
 NO_PUBKEY DCC9EFBF77E11517
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
648ACFD622F3D138
E: Release file for http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/InRelease is expired (invalid since 145d 4h 29min 16s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

My aforementioned `/etc/apt/sources.list` file is:

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Jessie_ - Official Multi-architecture amd6$

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Jessie_ - Official Multi-architecture amd64$

deb http://mirrors.linode.com/debian/ stable main
deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/debian/ stable main

deb http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://mirrors.linode.com/debian/ stable-updates main
deb [arch=i386,ppc64el,amd64] http://nyc2.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/debian stable main
# deb-src [arch=i386,ppc64el,amd64] http://nyc2.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/debian stable main

deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/debian/ stable-updates main
```

Doing some research on PPAs, I also updated my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list file to:

```
deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ stable main
```

But the error remains.

Is there a way to upgrade this PPA so it can be used with Debian Stable?  Or is there some other way around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just missing the signing keys; the packages in the new release are signed using new keys. You can get the keys from a key server and save them as new files in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`:

```
$ sudo gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-buster-automatic.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 648ACFD622F3D138
gpg: keyring '/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-buster-automatic.gpg' created
gpg: key DC30D7C23CBBABEE: public key "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (10/buster) <ftpmaster@debian.org>" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1

$ sudo gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-buster-stable.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv DCC9EFBF77E11517
gpg: keyring '/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-buster-stable.gpg' created
gpg: key DCC9EFBF77E11517: public key "Debian Stable Release Key (10/buster) <debian-release@lists.debian.org>" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

If the permissions of those files are something else, change them to `-rw-r--r--` using:

```
sudo chmod 644 /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-buster-automatic.gpg
sudo chmod 644 /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-buster-stable.gpg
```

The keys should now be listed in the output of `apt-key list` & the error with `apt update` be fixed.

Comment: You're adding the Ubuntu keyserver, however Major is using Lindoe. Will it compatible?

Comment: That did the trick!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For me, Debian 9 and installation of PHP 7.4, this works:

```
$ sudo wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
```

After that, I was able to run apt update without any error.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using a gpg2 keyring would not work due to debootstrap using `gpgv` under the hood, which uses a gpg1 database version. I recreated by gpg database like so from the [debian archive keyring server](https://ftp-master.debian.org/keys.html), note that `gpg` is gpg 1.x.x not gpg 2.x.x or newer at time of writing:

```
wget https://ftp-master.debian.org/keys/release-10.asc -qO- | gpg --import --no-default-keyring --keyring ./debian-release-10.gpg
debootstrap --keyring=./debian-release-10.gpg buster /srv/buster
```

---

If `deboostrap` were updated to use `gpg --verify` instead of `gpgv`, I would imagine `gpg2` could be used as a drop-in replacement - But I cannot be certain.